# How can I Filter a table with <select> using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, web, filter

I need help with a filter function on a table. For now I can Filter a table using Users input like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on( "keyup" ,function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

This works also great but how can I filter the table with a selection of the users. So the user could select a option:

```
<select name="Filter" id="myInput">
   <option id="myInput" value="error">John</option>
   <option id="myInput" value="error">Warning</option>
</select>
```

and after he selected something I would filter after this.
The table could looks like this:

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Log</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>dafsdfkj Error sdfkjlsdafj dsafjk</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Waring dfadf adf</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

thx for help<3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty much the same, except instead of using the `keyup` event you use `change`.

Also, you should use `.each()` rather than `filter()`, since you're not returning the value anywhere.

And you need to set the values of the options to what you want them to match, not `error`.

```js
$("#myInput").on("change", function() {
  var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $("#myTable tr").each(function() {
    $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="Filter" id="myInput">
  <option id="myInput" value="john">John</option>
  <option id="myInput" value="warning">Warning</option>
</select>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Log</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td>dafsdfkj Error sdfkjlsdafj dsafjk</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Warning dfadf adf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John did it</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you maybe make a JSFidle? Would be really nice

Comment: I created a stack snippet, it's essentially the same.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("change", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="Filter" id="myInput">
   <option   value="">All</option>
   <option   value="John">John</option>
   <option  value="Warning">Warning</option>
</select>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Log</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td>dafsdfkj Error sdfkjlsdafj dsafjk</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Warning dfadf adf</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>John did it</td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: John did it. Thanks for ur help